# Python AttributeError : Object has no attribute in QGIS Plugin

Tags: python, qgis, qpython

I'm trying to create a **GUI** with **QT Designer**. I've converted my *.ui* designer file to a *.py*.

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication 
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction, QIcon
from qgis.core import *
import resources
from delete_feature_dialog import DeleteFeatureDialog
import os.path

class DeleteFeature:

    def __init__(self, iface):
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&DeleteFeature')
        self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'DeleteFeature')
        self.toolbar.setObjectName(u'DeleteFeature')

    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):

        # Create the dialog (after translation) and keep reference
        self.dlg = DeleteFeatureDialog()

        ....

        return action

    def initGui(self):  
        icon_path = ':/plugins/DeleteFeature/icon.png'
        self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(u''),
            callback=self.run,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow())

    def run(self):
        #this code will populate the combo box with all vector layer
    self.dlg.layerListCombo.clear()
    layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    layer_list = []
    for layer in layers:
            layerType = layer.type()
            if layerType == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
                layer_list.append(layer.name())
    self.dlg.layerListCombo.addItems(layer_list)
        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code.
            selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.layerlistcombo.currentIndex()
            selectedLayer = layers [selectedLayerIndex]
            .....
```

Then when I open the plugin, I get the following error:

> 'DeleteFeatureDialog' objectObject has no attribute
>   'layerlistcombo'in QGIS Plugin

Any suggestion for this.

Comment: you have in this dialog a combobox?your objectname is layerlistcombo?probably no.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you wrote:

```
selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.layerlistcombo.currentIndex()
```

but you should have written:

```
selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.layerListCombo.currentIndex()
```

Like you did previously in your code (notice the Camel Notation when writing, not just lower-case letters), which is probably causing the `No Attribute` error you get.